# Nginx: how to get urls with /#/something

Tags: nginx, web, url, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm looking to add auth_basic into a specific location : domain.com/#/register
I've tried :

```
    location "/#/register" {
        ...
    }
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: No, there is no way to do it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897083/remove-web-index-html-from-plex-server-url#comment120019135_67897083) comment.

Comment: Do you think that I can check if the whole url contains 'register' or any string ? like
`if ($url.contain('register') {}`
or by regex `~  */register(*)`